# unit test for abstract base class method with user authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mocking, nunit

I have to write test case for a abstract base class method in below scenario:

```
     public abstract class baseclass{
     public bool MyBaseMethod(){
        if(User.Identity.IsAuthenticate)
         {.....}
       }
     }
     public class deriveclass: baseclass{
     }
```

In my test fixture class I have test method as:

```
     [Test]
      public void MyBaseMethodtest()
      {
       SetUserIdentity(true);
       var obj = new deriveclass();
       var result = obj.MyBaseMethod();

       //test cases follows
       ..........
       }
      private void SetUserIdentity(bool login = false)
      {
        var identity = new Mock<ClaimsIdentity>() { DefaultValue = DefaultValue.Mock };
        if (login)
        {
            identity.Setup(p => p.IsAuthenticated).Returns(true);
        }
        var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity.Object);
        var httpContext = new Mock<HttpContextBase> { DefaultValue = DefaultValue.Mock };
        httpContext.SetupGet(x => x.User).Returns(principal);
        controller.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext(httpContext.Object, new RouteData(), controller);

    }
```

but when I am trying to reference MyBaseMethod it gives null reference error for User object. I believe this is happening as I am setting controllercontext for derivedclass not for base class. 
I tried to google for similar scenarios but could not find any.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using the moq correctly, however you need to set the mock on the controller instance being used in the test, which seems to be the one being created in the line `var obj = new deriveclass();`, so when the method `SetUserIdentity` does `controller.ControllerContext = ...` is assigning the context to the instance you want to test. (I am assuming baseclass and deriveclass are controllers).

I have created the following controllers as your `baseclass` and `deriveclass`. I added a method named `FooMethod` in the base class that returns true when the user is authenticated and false otherwise:

```
public abstract class FooController : Controller
{
    public bool FooMethod()
    {
        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}

public class DerivedFooController : FooController
{
}
```

Your could then create a test method as follows (Notice that I am passing the controller under test to the `SetUserIdentity` method):

```
[Test]
public void FooMethodTest_ReturnsTrue_WhenUserIsAuthenticated()
{
    //Arrange
    var controllerUnderTest = new DerivedFooController();
    SetUserIdentity(controllerUnderTest, true);

    //Act
    var result = controllerUnderTest.FooMethod();

    //Asert
    Assert.IsTrue(result);
}

private void SetUserIdentity(ControllerBase controller, bool login = false)
{
    var identity = new Mock<ClaimsIdentity>() { DefaultValue = DefaultValue.Mock };
    if (login)
    {
        identity.Setup(p => p.IsAuthenticated).Returns(true);
    }
    var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity.Object);
    var httpContext = new Mock<HttpContextBase> { DefaultValue = DefaultValue.Mock };
    httpContext.SetupGet(x => x.User).Returns(principal);
    controller.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext(httpContext.Object, new RouteData(), controller);

}
```

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work...it is still giving same Null reference exception for user. I even tried to create obj as FooController basecontrollerobj = new DerivedFooController() and then call SetUserIdentity method but no luck :(

Comment: Have you tried copying the same code as in the answer? I have tested it with MSTest and it works. How are you calling `SetUserIdentity`? Have you added the new parameter to the SetUserIdentity method?

Comment: Found the problem in my code. I was faking controllercontext User identity followed by fake query string parameters. As they were done in two steps so fake user identity setting were getting lost. Change the implementation and after setting identity and query string parameters in single step resolve the issue.